# Google Apps Script CORS XML Request to Google Sites Blog Page

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, xmlhttprequest, cors, google-sites

I suspect this is a bit of an odd request, but I can only blame myself for building our company intranet on Google sites.

We use a Google Sites announcements page to publish a company blog. However, I want to design the intranet front-end to be responsive, which means we need Javascript to run on load, which Google Sites will not do. I can work around it by creating a Google Apps Script over which have full control, and I can already embed Google calendars to the new page in a responsive manner.

Since I cannot retrieve the announcements page as a gadget and insert into the apps script (as far as I know), I thought I would try to make an HTTP XML Request and format the results as I please. I'm pretty sure I can because I can view the XML Code through a web browser when I navigate to

> https://sites.google.com/a/MyCompany.com/intranet/home/myblog/posts.xml

Nevertheless, when I run my code, I get the following error:

> userCodeAppPanel:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://sites.google.com/a/Mycompany.com/intranet/home/mybog/posts.xml.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin
>   'https://n-ehgaacgvmatwqlcmd25gfeqoc7k4ky5rxijj2rq-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com'
>   is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code
>   403.

```
{"readyState":4,"status":404,"statusText":"error"}
```

It looks to me like Google Sites pages do not accept CORS requests. Is that true? Could someone help me get the XML Content from my Sites announcements page?

## Main HTML Page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('CSS').getContent(); ?>
  </head>
  <body onload="start()">
   <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('JS-Intranet').getContent();?>
  </body>
</html>
```

## JS-Intranet.html

```html
<script>
var adhcal = '<iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?</iframe>'
var clincal = '<iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?</iframe>';
var intranet = 'https://sites.google.com/a/mycompany';
var blogPath = '/intranet/home/myblog/posts.xml';
var url = 'https://sites.google.com/a/mycompany.com/intranet/home/myblog/posts.xml';


function start()
{
 var adhDiv = $('<div></div>').attr('id', 'adhDiv');
 $('body').append(adhDiv);
 adhDiv.width('100%').height('400');
 adhcal = adhcal.replace('height="100%"', 'height="'+adhDiv.height()+'"');
 adhDiv.append(adhcal);
 
 
$.ajax({
    url: intranet+'?path='+blogPath+'&type="text/html"',
    success: function (data) { 
        console.log('Page was succesfully retrieved');
        console.log(data.feed.entry[0].title); //print Page Title
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    },
    dataType: 'text/html'
});
 

}
</script>
```

A .gs file simply generates an HTML template from the Intranet.html document. All the lifting is done in JS.

Thank you,
        Nathaniel

Comment: you can do so using Google Site Gadgets You see m.sbctech.net. Here a gadget loading the announcement page feed from a different Google Site

Comment: Interesting suggestion. Because Google Appscript is not on the same domain as my Google Site, how can I embed any Google Sites Gadget? If I could, I would have just embedded the announcements page that I had in the first place. Not sure I fully understand your suggestion.

Comment: probably you know about Google Site Gadgets which are developed using XML. In that XML Gadget, you can bring the feed of the Announcement Page. Here is the gadget which I developed. If you check the source ( goo.gl/jtMYgd ), there I am using an Apps Script Gadget which returns feed of announcement page.

Comment: Other option is you create a Google Apps Script responsive gadget with HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL . This will allow to embed your apps script gadget anywhere on internet.

Comment: Wow, I didn't think to create my own XML Gadget for this. I guess I was hoping to save time and just use Google's standard tools. I see your XML Code is using a similar AJAX request but specifying a JSON transfer type. Let me try that with my code and see if I can avoid having to add an XML gadget to my project. Thank you very much, Waqar!